# Uncaught TypeMismatchError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having issues with the following snippet:

```
var o = $("#inserted_motive").find("span");
    $.contains(document.documentElement, o[0]) ? b.fillText(m, i, h) : b.drawImage(d, i, h, e, f);
    var p = a.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(p)
}), $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs()
});
```

The following error appears:

> Uncaught TypeMismatchError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLVideoElement object.

---

too answer the question;

```
 $("#creator").click(function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("final_image"),
        b = a.getContext("2d"),
        c = document.getElementById("shirt_main_canvas"),
        d = document.getElementById("inserted_image");
    b.drawImage(c, 0, 0);
    var e = $("#inserted_image").width(),
        f = $("#inserted_image").height(),
        g = $("#inserted_motive").position(),
        h = g.top,
        i = g.left,
        j = $("#inserted_motive span").css("font-size"),
        k = $("#inserted_motive span").css("font-family"),
        l = $("#inserted_motive span").css("color"),
        m = $("#inserted_motive span").text(),
        n = j + " " + k;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check what your `#inserted_image` is in your html, because it seems it's not either of :

- a valid HTMLImageElement
- a HTMLCanvasElement
- a HTMLVideoElement object